# Building a Rust Executable that requires Plotly's Kaleido

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, plotly-rust

I'm building a rust program for windows at work. I'm having issues getting Plotly+Kaleido to work properly on other computers. I do not have admin privileges on the other computers, and they are not connected to the internet.

I've built the executable in release mode. Using the executable directly on this computer works fine. It will save a static image.

Then I moved my executable over to another computer. Everything works correctly except for the part that requires Kaleido. It won't save a static image.

At first it was saying that it couldn't find Kaleido in the path, so I copied Kaleido over and added it to the path and it still couldn't find it. So I tracked down that it is requiring Kaleido to exist @ "C:\users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\plotly\kaleido" which is it's own problem. I then moved Kaleido to this location. It quit throwing the error message saying that it couldn't be found. It actually quit giving any kind of error message, but it also still doesn't save an image.

I feel like I must be misunderstanding something, but I'm at a loss right now as to how to proceed with debugging since I'm getting no error messages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "_I copied Kaleido over and added it to the path_", you mean the `PYTHONPATH` on the target machine right ? If not, this might be the issue.

Comment: I didn't mean PYTHONPATH. I'm using it through Rust, so I didn't think I'd need to do anything involving python. I just went and checked. The computer on which it is running correctly doesn't have a PYTHONPATH environment variable. I also tried adding it to PYTHONPATH on the failing computer and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I thought you were embedding some python code involving Plotly/Kaleido into your rust program (Plotly actually uses a python wrapper to run the Kaleido C++ standalone app).

Comment: I'm using https://crates.io/crates/plotly with the Kaleido feature enabled. On the development computer cargo takes care of the Kaleido install process for you. I'm not sure how to recreate. I'm currently waiting on IT to transfer the .whl file for me to try pip installing with that.

Comment: Update: using pip install on the .whl did not help